# Properties of Summation

Tags: summation

I need to get through

$\frac{1 - r^{n+1}}{1-r}$

only developing the mathematical expression

$(1-r) (\sum_{k=0}^n r^k)$

But when I do this (using addition and telescope) I only get to $1 - r^n+1 ...$

Can someone help  me?

Comment: It would improve your Question if you showed the approach taken (possibly some telescoping of terms in a series?) and where you feel the wrong conclusion was reached (or you found a dead end?).

Answer (score 1):

$(1 - r)*\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} r^i = [\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} r^i] - r*[\sum r^i;i=0..(n-1)]$

$ =   [\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} r^i] - [\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} r^{i+1}] $

$ =   [\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} r^i] - [\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^i] $

$= r^0 - r^n = 1 - r^n$

so for r $\neq$1;  $\frac{1 - r^n}{1 - r} = \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} r^i$

Comment: fair enough.  I was being lazy 'cause LaTex is a **** to type.  That's also why I didn't do the sum index right.  I'll fix that now.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q^k=S_n=1+\color{blue}{q+q^2+...+q^{n-1}} \quad (1)$

Now we multiply both sides by q.

$q\cdot S_n=\color{blue}{q+q^2+q^3+...+q^{n-1}}+q^{n} \quad (2)$

The blue marked terms are equal.

*$(1)-(2)$ gives*

$S_n-q\cdot S_n=1-q^n$

*Factoring out $S_n$ on the LHS.*

$S_n-q\cdot S_n=1-q^n$

$S_n(1-q)=1-q^n$

Dividing the equation by $1-q$ results in

$S_n=\frac{1-q^n}{1-q}$